# Is this my hosts fault or mine?

Tags: networking, server-side

On the net panel of my Firebug console some of the files sent with my website are racking up an alarming length of time "waiting" for a response from my server, and receiving certain files. I've done everything I can in terms of gzip, minifying code etc. and just wanted to confirm with someone who knows more than me about this stuff that the problem here is definitely with my (shared) server and not an issue.

Link to a (cropped) screenshot of the waterfall from the normal Firefox dev tools..

[screenshot](http://puu.sh/4tMsf.png)

I had just cleared my cache.
Also in reference to anyone who might point out that it's my fault for buying a plan with a cheap, slow host on a shared plan.. please don't, I am already well aware :p

Comment: You could check that out by serving your stuff from your own machine. If you get long delays locally, shame on you; Otherwise, shame on your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

It is host's fault. Because you say you are stuck on `waiting`not at `receiving`, stuff like gzip will not work. Waiting state will be there until server responses with at least 1 byte. If the problem would be with size it would be receiving speed problem, not a waiting one.
Yhis looks like the host is overloaded, or you have very low-speed connection with it.